# Xamarin Bound Service Connection method can I instantiate a class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mqtt

I am trying to understand bound services.  I have an xamarin app using mqtt and the mqtt is getting disrupted during the activity lifecycle.  Currently I have a connection class that handles the connection to the mqtt that is called from an activity.

I need the connection class to run without interruption regardless if app is in foreground background etc.  (if anyone is curious the keepalive routine gets interrupted when the app goes into the background) The app is 100% stable if I don't let the phone go to sleep (developer option stay awake while charging).  If I let the phone go to sleep after a while the mqtt gets disconnected.

So from what I am understanding I need a boundService, boundServiceBinder, and boundServiceConnection classes.

It looks like I want the heavy lifting to happen in the boundServiceConnection class.

Example

```
class BoundServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection  
{  
        Connection connect;

        public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)  
        {  
                connect = new connection();

        }  
        public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)  
        {  
        }  
}
```

Now will this work, will I be able to access the properties of the connection class as I am able to when I instantiate in an activity?

Thanks all

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,

what you want to do is just create a method in you boundServiceConnection class that instantiates the object. and call it after you have bound to the service